# browser-side OpenAPI request validation (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, openapi

How can i validate a request against a given openAPI spec on the client side in browser environment?

I spent hours of searching and trying openapi-tools but each one is designed for use in nodejs and therefore do not work. I want this for an e2e test in cypress for my react app without setting up a mock server or backend.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might face the same problem. The list of [openapi-tools](https://openapi.tools/) provides several libraries for validation but most of them are made for nodejs environment and do not work in browser environment. But i manged to get two of them running with polyfills which is needed if you use webpack v5. The two working ones are [openapi-request-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-request-validator) and [oa-client](https://github.com/ninofiliu/oa-client) in combination with [swagger-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-client). I would definitely recommend the oa-client because openapi-request-validator could not validate url-parameter and formdata properly. If I might have missed some other way for validation I'm open for recommendations.